# Implement API key solution for Sail.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to make an option such that I can issue 3rd part developers access to my data and to do so, similar to the following: https://docs.sharedcount.com/, I want to create a system wherein those developers are provided an API key for which the consumption count can be monitored

Came through Waterlock but does not look like it has this feature: http://waterlock.ninja/

Curious, what would be the best approach to implement API keywords for a Sail.js app?

Answer (score 3):

Sails makes this incredibly easy by use of policies. When a user signs up, assign them an API key, and then create a policy that checks the params for a valid API key -- i.e. `req.param('APIKey')` -- and deny access if one is not found.

Comment: Ah cool, did not know that, that was the use case of policies - thanks so much :-)